# Collision detection in Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-engine, 2d-games

I'm working on my first Unity project. It's a little game where you have to move your planet to dodge incoming asteroids.

I have set up a simple collision detection system but it's not working at this moment and I'm not entirely sure why.

These are the lines of codes, they're on the movement script for the planet, attached to my gameobject planet:

```
private void OnTriggeredEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Asteroid")
    {
        restartPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

The asteroids are a prefab spawned dynamically in this manner in a script attached to an invisible gameobject:

```
void Update()
{
    float interval = Time.deltaTime;
    random = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
    Debug.Log(interval);
    Debug.Log(random);
    if (interval > random) {
        GameObject newAsteroid = Instantiate(asteroidPrefab, GetRandomPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
        newAsteroid.GetComponent<Gravity>().planet = planet;
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when planet collides with any asteroid, or when asteroids collide with each other, if that matters, and I'm not entirely sure why.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The method name was not correct, I messed up, it should have been OnTriggerEnter2D, not OnTriggeredEnter2D.

Yikes.